# How to prevent users from deleting cookies and browsing data on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I share my computer at work and sometimes other users delete their browsing data and history. I'm the administrator and I would like to prevent anybody from being able to delete cookies and site data. I have managed to prevent the manual deletion of the browsing history by adding an entry to the Registry Editor, but I haven't been able to do the same with cookies and other browsing data.

Comment: Cookies and personal data is unique to the userid. Use different userid's for each user.

Comment: @John, yup and remember, many cookies preserve login details. It would be a wonderful way to access someones bank  account.

Comment: Bank Accounts should be in Credential Manager (not cookies) or the browser password manager and that is also unique to the user profile.

Comment: The reason for me wanting to keep cookies and site data is that I want a number of websites to be shown a certain way. Let's say for example Youtube recommendations. I'm not interested in other personal info that the browser it's not saving, like passwords. That's disabled.

Comment: It may be better to have your own computer to keep sensitive data secret.

Comment: Alternatively create a guest user you can share to protect your own info. Teach your colleagues who want to access private stuff on your system to use browser's Private mode. Youtube recommendations are tied to google account used to login, so it's worthwhile remembering that anyone who has access to that youtube account has access to the google account.

Comment: Unless you plan and removing the permissions to delete the Chrome profile folder itself, you can implement all the safeguards within Chrome, but removing the entire user profile will delete your Chrome user profile data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a problem of social interaction, rather than of computers. As the poster rejects software solutions, this post does not fit our site.